# What type of asbestos is this?

Tags: asbestos

I have a 1960's dormer-bungalow (UK).  I'm currently having a back extension which requires removal of the old soffits.

The soffits are boarded with asbestos. (Photo below)

[image]

By looking at this, is it possible to tell what type of asbestos this is?  I want to know what I'm dealing with before getting quotes for removal.

Comment: In terms of abatement, I don't know that the 'type' of asbestos matters at all. They're all dangerous in certain forms. In this case, the form is 'friable' in that removing it will create dust. This is the most dangerous form for it to exist in. (On the plus side, it sounds like this is outdoors, so less of a concern)

Comment: Though all dangerous, the type of asbestos does matter.  Different kinds of asbestos correspond with different levels of risk of getting cancer.

Comment: erionite, amphibole series, chrysotile -- from short fiber to long fiber. The worst is erionite which is too short for industrial use, forming micro-needles that blow in the dust in the Pacific Northwest. You breath it just by living here during drouths.